# Why can't we use an integer variable as a by part of the floating type variable?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I just wanted to ask that if say I initialize an integer variable like

```
int a = 9;
```

Then, why can't we use this integer value as a by part for the initialization of the `float` variable, like If I try to write

```
float g=a.0;
```

why is this statement actually an error?

What is the problem that is caused inside a compiler when I write this statement?

Comment: When the integer variable gets subtituted by its value ,so then what is the problem here that is caused.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? do you have a good reason for that?

Comment: Just remove the `.0` and it will work. Just `float g=a;` is enough

Comment: You can't just invent new notation like you can in pseudocode

Comment: Just write something like `int a = 3; int b = 14; float g = a + b/10.0f; // 3.14`

Comment: Because `a` is not replaced with `9` as you might assume.

Comment: @Lundin this will result in `4.4`, not `3.14`. You should do `b/100.0f`.

Comment: @mch Err yeah of course. Anyway, that is how you do it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is just not `C` syntax. The only way you use a dot like this is when you access `struct` members.

To cast `int` to `float`, just:

```
int i = 5;
float f = i;
```

There is even no need to cast, as pmg suggested.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when initializing globals.

Answer (score 2):

The problem caused inside the compiler when you write this statement is that the statement does not follow the syntax defined for the C language in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf). Thus there is no way to know what it means. To you it is obvious what it should mean, but unlike natural languages, in programming languages things must be defined before being used, and it was never defined what `a.0` should mean.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is an operator (the same way that `!` or `+` is an operator). The compiler looks at `a`, and decides it can't apply the `.` operator to it.

If `a` were a struct, then it might be possible to apply `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print the `int` value as if it was `float`, i.e. with decimal places, for that you can just use the `printf()` `float` specifier to make it print the `int` as a `float`.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    int x = 4;
    printf("%.1f", (float)x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, C only uses . as a decimal point in floating point constants, like 2.171828 or for structure members, like mystruct.member.

However, the idea of using floating point arrays to hold integers is how many large number (arbitrary precision) libraries operate, such as apfloat.